# struts2 making me go mad

Tags: java, struts2, type-conversion, struts2-interceptors, interceptorstack

I have been trying to make a java project. Its using Struts 2 tags. There is a button <kbd>Update</kbd> whenever it is to be clicked, it should update the values in the database.

But I am getting this error:

> No result defined for action com.comviva.im.ui.action.sysadmin.CUGAction and result input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> No result defined for action
>   com.comviva.im.ui.action.sysadmin.CUGAction and result input

This means that you are lacking the mapping for the `input` result for this Action in your Struts.xml

The standard workflow

> JSP -> Interceptor Stack -> Action

is breaking BEFORE reaching the Action, most likely by the ConversionError Interceptor (eg. sending a String to an Integer, for example), and it is returning back without even reaching the Action.

Read more on [**Struts2 INPUT result**: how does it work? How are conversion / validation errors handled?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23450365/1654265)

When trying to come back, it can't find where to go.

So you must define an `input` result type:

```xml
<action name="CUGAction" class="com.comviva.im.ui.action.sysadmin.CUGAction">
    <result name="success">/your.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/your.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Then print out the error in your JSP [with `<s:fielderror />`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30025745/1654265) and [with `<s:actionerrors />`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13154159/1654265), and try to figure out what is happening.

Comment: Just a note: from result configuration `Likewise if the name attribute is not specified, the framework will give it the name "success".` http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/result-configuration.html

Comment: I would not call that a bad practice, "Intelligent Defaults" instead. :)