# Struts2 Action validator, delegates validation to the model with the 'type="visitor" ' attribute

Tags: java, xml, validation, struts2, visitor-pattern

I am facing the issue in Struts2 validation.

My Action class is `NotificationsAction`

My Model class is `UserNotificationsForm` .

I have created the `NotificationsAction-validation.xml`

```
<validators>         
    <field name="userNotificationForm">
        <field-validator type="visitor">
            <param name="appendPrefix">false</param>
            <message/>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
```

and `UserNotificationsForm-notifications_update-validation.xml` is

```
<field name="userNotificationForm.email">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <message key="register.validation.email" />
    </field-validator>
    <field-validator type="email-custom">
        <message key="register.validation.email.format" />
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

When i am inserting the wrong email it is not validating properly

Comment: Not clear where your visitor validation filename comes from. Is `notifications_update` your method ? Not sure you can use visitor like that. Try renaming it to `UserNotificationsForm-validation.xml`, and ensure it is on the same path of `UserNotificationsForm`, NOT the action's path.

Comment: notifications_update is a method. UserNotificationsForm-validation.xml  i tried this way also not getting any luck

Comment: It must be the name of the Java class, not the instance. Is it ? And is it in the path I asked you to verify ?

Comment: Does email-custom works ?

Comment: yes email-custom is working fine. path is same for UserNotificationsForm and UserNotificationsForm-notifications_update-validation.xml

Comment: when i put the correct email in form then action's method is executed , in case of wrong email method is not invoke

Comment: LOL ! That's the normal behavior ! If the validation fails, it will return INPUT ***before*** reaching the Action method. Configure INPUT result and `<s:fielderror>` and you will see. This is different from "it is not validating prperly". [Read more on this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13379721/1654265)

Comment: but in other case action method are invoked and in that method we check the ArrayList<ErrorMsgForm> errorList = doGenericValidation();.

Comment: sorry may be i am doing some silly mistake because its working fine this way in my project.