# To check whether that user already exists or not in struts2

Tags: java, validation, jsp, struts2, struts2-interceptors

Here I want if the user is trying to register with the code that already exists in my table then it should provide an error that

> This code is already taken please try with different one.

Using Struts2 I want to do this. Below is my action class.

What I have done is: first I have fired a query for selecting code using resultset and stored all the results in a String variable `temp_user` and in `validate()` method I have just compared it using `equals(temp_user)` method, but it doesn't work.

RegisterAction.java

```
package org.entity;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.wsdl.Message;

import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;

import nl.captcha.Captcha;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class RegistrationAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {
    BloodBank register;
    private Map<String, Object> session;
    private String temp_user;

    public BloodBank getRegister() {
        return register;
    }

    public void setRegister(BloodBank register) {
        this.register = register;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getSession() {
        return session;
    }

    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public String getTemp_user() {
        return temp_user;
    }

    public void setTemp_user(String temp_user) {
        this.temp_user = temp_user;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foryou", "root", "siddheshkk");
            System.out.println("Driver Loaded");
            Statement st12 = con.createStatement();
            PreparedStatement st = con
                    .prepareStatement("insert into bbinfo(code,name,address,city,district,contactno,stdcode,password,aname,email) "
                            + "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            st.setString(1, register.getCode());
            st.setString(2, register.getBbname());
            st.setString(3, register.getAddress());
            st.setString(4, register.getCity());
            st.setString(5, register.getDistrict());
            st.setString(6, register.getNumber());
            st.setString(7, register.getStd());
            st.setString(8, register.getPassword());
            st.setString(9, register.getAname());
            st.setString(10, register.getEmail());
            st.executeUpdate();
            st.close();

            PreparedStatement st1 = con
                    .prepareStatement("insert into stockinfo(name,city,address,contact,email,code,stdcode,apositive,anegative,bpositive,bnegative,abpositive,abnegative,opositive,onegative)"
                            + "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0')");
            st1.setString(1, register.getBbname());
            st1.setString(2, register.getCity());
            st1.setString(3, register.getAddress());
            st1.setString(4, register.getNumber());
            st1.setString(5, register.getEmail());
            st1.setString(6, register.getCode());
            st1.setString(7, register.getStd());
            st1.executeUpdate();
            st1.close();
            System.out.println("done");
            ResultSet rs12 = st12.executeQuery("select code from bbinfo");
            while (rs12.next()) {
                temp_user = rs12.getString("code");
            }

            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "success";
    }

    @Override
    public void validate() {
        super.validate();
        if (register.getCode().length() < 1 | register.getCode().equals("")) {
            addFieldError("register.code", "Mandatory Field.");
        }
        if(register.getCode().equals(getTemp_user()))
        {
            addFieldError("register.code", "This Code is already taken. Please try different one.");
        }
        if (register.getBbname().equals("") | register.getBbname().length() < 1) {
            addFieldError("register.bbname", "Invalid Name");
        }
        if (register.getAddress().equals("")) {

            addFieldError("register.address", "Invalid Address");
        }
        if (register.getCity().equals("")) {
            addFieldError("register.city", "Invalid City");

        }
        if (register.getDistrict().equals("")) {
            addFieldError("register.district", "Invalid District");

        }
        if (register.getPassword().length() > 8
                | register.getPassword().equals("")) {
            addFieldError("register.password", "Please Enter a valid Password");
        }
        if (!(register.getConfirm().equals(register.getPassword()))) {
            addFieldError("register.confirm", "Password doesnt match");
        }
        if (register.getConfirm().isEmpty()) {
            addFieldError("register.confirm", "Please enter confirmed password");
        }
        if (register.getAname().equals("")) {
            addFieldError("register.aname", "Please enter your name");
            ;
        }
        if (register.getEmail().equals("")) {
            addFieldError("register.email", "Invalid Email Id");
        } else {
            String expression = "^[\\w\\-]([\\.\\w])+[\\w]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$";
            CharSequence inputStr = register.getEmail();
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression,
                    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
            if (!matcher.matches())
                addFieldError("register.email", "Invalid email address");
        }
        Captcha captcha = (Captcha) session.get(Captcha.NAME);
        if (!(captcha.isCorrect(register.getCaptchaAnswer()))) {
            addFieldError("register.captchaAnswer", "incorrect captcha");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How would the user know the code you selected from the table?

Comment: yes i have got errors in the validate method where that equals condition for code begins .

Comment: i didnt get you roman sir . i have fetched all the records using resultset in string variable and later on i am comparing it in validation method

Comment: Actually i am not getting any error .user gets registered with the duplicate name too . it doesnt give any error at the required field :(

Comment: Please anyone help me with the solution :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the `validate()` method, run by the [Validation Interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/docs/validation-interceptor.html), 
is executed **before reaching the action**, and hence before the `execute()` method.

This means that `temp_user` is always null when read in the `validate()` method.

You need to learn how Struts2 works, especially when and how [the Interceptors are called between the JSP and the Action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13379721/1654265).

> **Solution**: load the `temp_user` variable inside the `validate()` method.

Also read [Should I retrieve database record in Struts2 view layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13837913/1654265) for a discussion on how to make your code cleaner and more decoupled, because all that JDBC stuff in the action is really ugly.

Comment: Okay thanks alot sir :) but what do you mean by loading a variable in validate method ? .   String temp_user; ResultSet rs12 = st12.executeQuery("select code from bbinfo");
            while (rs12.next()) {
                temp_user = rs12.getString("code");
            }
Should i write this code in validate method and then compare ?

Comment: Exactly. In `validate()` you have the one coming from the page, but not the other that will be loaded in `execute()`. Load it in `validate()` instead that in `execute()`, if your goal is only to compare them.

Comment: Yes Sir i will just try that and will let u know and if i succeed i will mark the answer which helped me :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Andrea Sir for Suggestion and it really helped me. :)
I wrote following code in Validate() method and my code was executed Successfully. Thanks alot again sir :) and the link posted by you also cleared my concept of how interceptors should be called between and JSP and Action. :) Below is my code.

```
String temp_user = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foryou", "root", "siddheshkk");
            System.out.println("Step 1");
            Statement st12 = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs12 = st12.executeQuery("select code from bbinfo");
            while (rs12.next()) {

                temp_user = rs12.getString("code");
                System.out.println("step2");
                if (register.getCode().equals(temp_user)) {
                    addFieldError("register.code",
                            "This username is already taken .Try Different one !");
                    System.out.println("sid");
                }

            }
            st12.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```