# No result defined for action after using autocomplete in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, autocomplete, struts2-jquery

I am getting an error of No result defined for action for result input. It was not coming till the time I used Struts 2 autocomplete.

**This is my `autocomplete` code :**

```jsp
<s:form class="form-horizontal" style="margin:0 auto" role="form" theme="simple" action="Reports_open_cases">
 <h4>Open Cases</h4>

  ..some controls here

<div class="form-group">              
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4"></div>
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4" >
 <s:url id="advURL" action="xyz_action"/>    
<sj:select 
 id="abc"  
 name="abc" selectBoxIcon="true"
 href="%{advURL}" 
 list="list_abc" 
 listValue="name" 
 listKey="Id "  
 autocomplete="true"  
 cssClass="form-control"
/>  
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 pull-right" style="text-align:right"><br>
     <div class="modal-footer" style="margin:0px; padding:10px 0px 10px">
             <button class="btn btn-success"  type="submit">Generate</button>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;        
            <button class="btn btn-default"  type="Reset">Reset</button>
      </div>
</div>
</s:form>
```

**My `struts.xml` (Action):**

```xml
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="20000000" />      
<package name="login" extends="struts-default,json-default" namespace="/">
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor class="vercelon.actions.LoginInterceptor" name="loginInterceptor">
        </interceptor>    
        <interceptor-stack name="loginStack">
        <interceptor-ref name="loginInterceptor"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"><param name="maximumSize">10485760</param>
  </interceptor-ref>
    </interceptor-stack>  
      
    </interceptors>    

<action name="Reports_open_cases" class="vercelon.actions.Report" 
                                 method="Generate_OpenCases">
    <result name="success">/CMS/Reports_OpenCases.jsp</result>
    <result name="ERROR">/Error.jsp</result> 
    <result name="input">/CMS/Reports_Menu.jsp</result>
</action> 

<action name="xyz_action" class="vercelon.actions.Report" method="loadreports">
        <result name="success" type="json"></result>
    </action>
```

Other then replacing the dropdown to the autocomplete, I haven't made any other changes.

When I add input to my `struts.xml` it doesn't show this error. But the action defined to my form submit doesn't work either.

I don't understand where I need to make changes after adding this autocomplete.

Comment: After you've added input result use `fielderror` and `actionerror` tags to display error(-s) in that page.

Comment: Ya ok I will do that

Comment: It doesnt show any error

Comment: I only added the tags to the input result jsp. What else do I need to do??

Comment: I have added it to the qustn

Comment: Well turn on logging/dev mode and see if there is some error in console.

Comment: Please post your 1) package declaration and interceptor stack 2) JSP <form> opening tag and <submit> button 3) error in system out or logfile

Comment: @AndreaLigios I have edited the qustn. But I tried again removing the autocomplete then its working fine. I think it has something to do with the auto complete only.

Comment: BTW `defaultStack` already includes `fileUpload` interceptor, and you are including it again. So you have 2 `fileUpload` interceptors in your stack.

Comment: tnx I will remove it.

Comment: Also add namespace="/" to your s:form and s:url, and please post config for xyz_action

Comment: Ya added in the qustn

Comment: It doesn't have an input result defined :)

Comment: Thnaks but input error comes in `Reports_open_cases` action. I added input result for xyz_action, doesnt make any difference.

Comment: `But the action defined to my form submit doesnt work either. ` what is happening then ? Check with firebug/firefox/chrome etc NET console

Answer (score 2):

When you call some action from the view layer the interceptors run before the action is executed.

Seems your actions use default stack which include `validation` and `workflow` interceptors. First interceptor performs validations on actions that extend `ActionSupport`, the second check if there were errors the `INPUT` result is returned.

But if you use some `-validation.xml` or annotation based validations on action class, so every action that is mapped the method of this class is validated by the interceptors above, unless you have configured these interceptors to exclude a method, or use prefixed based method of validation, or skip validation annotation is applied.

All these cases to avoid running validators for the code that haven't been used by some action and needs to avoid them or reconfigure interceptor stack to run without these interceptors.

In your case the action that returns `json` result doesn't need validation of fields rather than a `term`. How to configure and override interceptors configuration of the action see in question: [How to get result on same page why input is required?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26243070/573032).

The working example that uses [Select Box with JSON Result as Autocompleter](https://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/autocompleter-select.action).

The source code for the `Autocompleter` [The actions source code used in the example](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/blob/release/4.1.x/struts2-jquery-showcase/src/main/java/com/jgeppert/struts2/jquery/showcase/Autocompleter.java).

Comment: @R Thanks a lott. adding `<interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>` solved  the input error issue. But now it isnt passing the value of autocomplete to the action class.

Comment: Which value? Post the action's classes, they should have both setters.