# How does the validate() method in Struts 2 get the result "input"?

Tags: java, validation, jakarta-ee, struts2, struts2-interceptors

In Struts 2, `"input"` is returned when a check fails in the `validate()` method. I then map `<result name="input">` in `struts.xml` for the appropriate page.

**I am just wondering how it gets the `"input"`, which is a `String` when the `validate()` method itself returns `void`?**

```
@Override
public void validate() {
    // if checks here
}
```

I would like to understand this concept.

Comment: You can read the docs for this or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26367502/573032) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18504177/573032).

Comment: Well you need to add field or action errors. The framework runs validate, setting these values into a map, if the map is empty then it runs execute(). You can also take a look a the code (add sources using maven) and then inspect ActionSupport and you can see the action side of the code (not the calling side) but it should be clear enough how that works. You supply functionality which struts2 calls and figures out what to do. Typical framework programming, it follows the Hollywood pattern: You don't call us, we call you.

Comment: You may find this a good read: [Struts2 INPUT result: how does it work? How are conversion / validation errors handled?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23450365/1654265)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `validate()` method itself returns nothing (`void`). It's invoked by [`validation` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/validation-interceptor.html).

But after this interceptor usually is going [`workflow` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/default-workflow-interceptor.html). This interceptor is responsible to return `INPUT` result if the action `hasErrors()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for actually providing an answer to this.